# PHP POST not working: Returning empty array

Tags: php, post

Look at the following PHP:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

I am running this program using the following URL:

```
http://192.168.2.1:8888/a-s/bootstrap/php/test.php?lookup_word=parrot
```

And the result I am getting is this:

```
array(0) { }
```

What sorcery is this? Why is it returning an empty array while I am feeding it at least one key-value pair?

Comment: seeing `?lookup_word=parrot`, I am guessing you want `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: Please learn the concept of `$_GET` and `$_POST` . You're mixing up these

Comment: It's because your not getting the variable you defined in you URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your not getting the variable you defined in your URL.

you should do it like this:

```
var_dump($_GET['lookup_word']);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for `looking_word` parameter in `$_POST` variable, you won't get it as its part of a GET request and will be available in `$_GET`. If you want to make it general you can check `$_REQUEST` variable.

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

As others mentioned, please have a look into the GET and POST concepts and `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` variables.

Answer (score -1):

It's returning an empty array simply because the `$_POST` array in empty. You have not POSTED any data for `$_POST` to fetch.

Passing arguments via the URL sets them to `$_GET` not `$_POST` to set data to `$_POST` you have to POST data via an HTML form, curl etc

try

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Also please learn more about [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) & [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)